# How to send form data and display them dynamically with ajax in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form that have a text area field I already store my data in the tables but now I want to show the results in same page with ajax dynamicly its mean that I want to refresh page without reloading

```html
<form action='' method='post''>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment"></label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name='message_content' required></textarea>
</div>
                                                                             
                                                                             
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default' name='send_msg'>
                                                           send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you show us some code ? What did you try ? Are you using a javascript library ?

Comment: I added code I have this form I want to show the results with ajax in same page above the text area

Comment: No I don't use any js

Comment: Do you want to show the comments in the same page after they are submitted.

Comment: No no just the message in the text area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a strong advocate on using javascript framework, however, ajax is a pain to handle without it, so here is an example using JQuery, but it's possible to do more or less the same thing with any other framework.

The first step is to intercept the submit event, then get the form data, perform an ajax query and display results in a div.

```
<!DOCTYPE doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#myForm').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: e.currentTarget.action,
                    data:{
                        comment: jQuery('#comment').val()
                    }
                }).done(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    jQuery('#display-data').append(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" action="getData.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">
                </label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="message_content" required="" rows="5">
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" name="send_msg" type="submit">
                send
            </button>
        </form>
        <div id="display-data"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** From your comment, I gathered you wanted to reload page after submission, you can do it after at the end of your ajax query :

```
jQuery('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: e.currentTarget.action,
        data:{
            comment: jQuery('#comment').val()
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        document.location.reload();
    });
});
```

Comment: bro tnx for your response but I think you don't understand my mean Can I have your social network id as like skype or whats app

Comment: Could you tell me what I misunderstood. I would prefer to answer on this site and not with any other social mean, that way, the answer might benefit someone else.

Comment: I want to give you my source actually its a social network that I created my question is about chat system but my  system is full php because of that I need to reload the page each time after sending the message but I need to do that with ajax or jquery